# How to use Google Python client in Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-python-client

I'm making a REST API using Google Cloud Endpoints.

My API provides event service such as Google Calendar Event.

But my event model has additional properties unlike Google Calendar.

so I want to store additional properties into my datastore.

and the others store Google Calendar API.

by the way I don't know how to OAuth2 authenticate for using Google API Python Client.

```
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
    client_id='',
    client_secret='',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

@space_api.api_class(resource_name='events')
class EventsApi(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(EVENT_RESOURCE, EventMessage,
                    path='events', http_method='POST',
                    name='events.insert')
  @decorator.oauth_required
  def events_insert(self, request):
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=encode_message(request)).execute(http=decorator.http())
    return decode_message(EventMessage, event)
```

I use OAuth2Decorator but remote.Service class has no redirect method.

so it causes an error.

What should I do for using Google API Python client in Google Cloud Endpoints.

Please let me know how to authenticate OAuth2.

Welcome any comment such as documentation link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an API in which a methods for that API need authentication go through the document [1]. You want to create an API which needs authentication use the docs [2]. To use OAuth in Google API Python Client go through the document [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/auth

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications. Since you are using google cloud end point with App engine, you can use AppAssertionCredentials to make an authorized API call to Google Calendar API. Below is the modified code:

```
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
calendar_service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)

@space_api.api_class(resource_name='events')
class EventsApi(remote.Service):

  @endpoints.method(EVENT_RESOURCE, EventMessage,
                    path='events', http_method='POST',
                    name='events.insert')
  def events_insert(self, request):
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=encode_message(request)).execute(http_auth)
    return decode_message(EventMessage, event)
```

You can find more details here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#callinganapi